# How to perform cross-site scripting attack testing that has actionable feedback?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, security, xss

I have a site security monitor that just recently started raising errors about cross-site scripting attacks.  I've found the test results to be quite lacking in actual details for issue resolution.

**Is there a de facto test suite or methodology to follow for finding and resolving XSS issues?**  This particular platform is built on Rails 3.1.x and I was under the impression that Rails took some measures to ensure that XSS issues were carefully handled by default now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases XSS is very obvious,  but not always.   There are a lot of ways of executing JavaScript in an html document.   The [XSS prevention rules](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#XSS_Prevention_Rules) are a very good description of the different ways XSS can happen.

As a ruby programmer you should read the [Ruby on Rails Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html).